# I'm using .toString() inside of linq - does it caching the converted value or does repeatedly converting it on each pass of the cycle?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

The code example:

```
var id = 2;
var result = data.Where(x => x.SomeField.Any(p => p.Id == id.ToString()))
```

It seems it is converting int to string on each pass of the cycle:

[image]

Where I can check this type of behavior, to be sure?

Comment: I'm surprised by the answers, didn't know that. When you use Linq queries in database calls, only one query is sent to the server, treating `id.ToString()` as a constant value. The solution is of course to put the string value in a variable.

Comment: Well, there's no way that query could be translated to SQL, so it would have to be done in memory and `.ToString()` would be called each time.

Comment: @DStanley: Unless you cache it in a variable (since it wont change).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a test and it appears to call `ToString` for each item in data. I modified the code and used a special class below.

```
public class SpecialInt
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator int(SpecialInt x)
    {
        return x.Value;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ToString is called");
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then I ran the code below

```
var id = new SpecialInt { Value = 2 };
var result = data.Where(x => x.SomeField.Any(p => p.Id == id.ToString())).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(result.Count);
```

`data` contained two objects complying with the predicate.

Output was

```
ToString is called
ToString is called
2
```

The above behavior makes sense. Basically `Where` is a loop and an instruction is executed for each object. `ToString` is also an instruction and the runtime must execute it each time since the return value could change.

Answer (score 0):

If this is an Entity Framework call, then the following statement will perform a single query on the server and therefore convert your id prior to its execution:

```
var result = data.Include(x => x.SomeField.Where(y => y.Id == id.ToString())).ToList();
```

But, I'm gonna go out on a limb and say that you probably don't really want this since it feels like a symptom of a wider issue.
I recommend posting your object graph so that we can see why this is even being asked in the first place.